# Number of automorphisms of $\mathbb Z _{91}$ of order 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Solution verification, I think I have the answer worked out,  just want my logic checked.

Looking for the number of automorphisms of order 3 in $Aut(\mathbb Z _{91})$. 
So, $91=7\cdot13$, and we have the $Aut(\mathbb Z_{91})\cong \mathbb Z _{91}^*$, the multiplicative group.  By the Chinese remainder theorem, $\mathbb Z _{91}^*\cong \mathbb Z _{13}^* \times \mathbb Z _{7}^*$.  So, I need elements of order 3 in the two smaller groups, and at least one element of order 3 in the ordered pair (With possibly the identity in the other).

$|\mathbb Z _{7}^*|=6$ and it's abelian, since there is only one abelian group of that order, it is cyclic, hence there is a unique element of order 3.  $|\mathbb Z _{13}^*|=12$, so there are two abelian groups.  I calculated out $2^n$ mod 13 and found that it had order 12, so $2$ generates the entire group, hence it is cyclic and it has a unique element of order 3.   Thus, calling the elements of order 3 in the two groups $a$ and $b$ respectively,  I have three automorphisms:  $(a,1),(1,b),(a,b)$ of order 3.

Is this correct/valid?

Edit for correctness:  There's a unique SUBGROUP of order 3, not a unique element of order 3 in each of those cyclic groups, which means there are two elements of order 3. As per @Bill Cook, that makes $3^2 -1=8$ possibilities, not $2^2-1=3$ as I had above.

Comment: What about $(b,1)$, $(1,a)$, $(b,a)$, $(a,a)$, and $(b,b)$? $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ are indeed cyclic. Both have orders ($13-1=12$ and $7-1=6$) divisible by 3, so they both have 2 elements of order 3 plus 1 of order 1 (identity). There are $3 \cdot 3 =9$ ways to combine these elements as ordered pairs. Toss out the identity and get $9-1=8$ elements of order 3.

Comment: Doh, I forgot and replaced "Unique subgroup" with "Unique element",  so yeah, 2 elements, 1 subgroup.   Thanks!